# How to develop an Open Identity provider using Java

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, single-sign-on, saml

[image of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaj8q.png) I am intended to set up a SAML SSO with my web app. I am currenty having a web app that has its own two step verification process for validating the users. I need to configure this web app as my **Identity provider** and use the website https://velpic.com as my **Service provider**. This website supports SSO and for accessing this website the user has to be first authenticated in the web app and should maintain a SSO in the website. I already have my java webapp running in tomcat 9.0 and now need to implement this. Can any one help me with getting started?. And i dont want to user any external Idp providers.

Comment: You must install an identity provider, then export its metadata. The metadata must then be imported by the service provider.

Comment: I want my web-app to act as the identity provider and ensure user authentication.

Comment: OK, is it SAML-compliant? do you know how to establish a trust relationship witn the service provider?

Comment: Yes it is a SAML-compliant  and i dont know about the trust cerificates or how to create them.

Comment: The SP must have a way to register your IDP. You need to talk with the guys that run the SP.

Comment: The website which acts as my sp accepts metadata config and i need to upload my metadata config in the website and it will create a trust relationship

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps to do this. Im stuck in configuring my webapp as the IDp

Comment: I can't tell you that: I don't know your webapp.

Comment: I have a normal  java servlet webapp which has a login page and it verifies the users with their username and password and maintains a database in mysql. i just wnat my webapp to authenticate the user and generate a SAML assertion which will then be used for logging in to the website.

Comment: Well you'll need a little more than a login page to do that.

Comment: can u brief me on this?